# How to run JavaScript inside an iframe

Tags: javascript, iframe

In my main page, an iframe is being loaded like this:

```
 <div class="row iframe">
   <iframe  class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-lg-12" name="inlineframe" src="myphpfile"     height="100%" width="100%" frameborder="0"></iframe>
 </div>
```

**This code works fine when not in an iframe, how can I run this javascript when inside an iframe?**

```
<script>
function checkthis()
{      
$('#btn').prop('disabled', false);  
}
</script>


<form name='opt' action='check' role='form' method='post'>          
    <label class='block'><input type='radio' name='ans' value='A' onclick='checkthis();'>  $opt1</label>
    <label class='block'><input type='radio' name='ans' value='B' onclick='checkthis();'>  $opt2</label>
    <label class='block'><input type='radio' name='ans' value='C' onclick='checkthis();'>  $opt3</label>
    <label class='block'><input type='radio' name='ans' value='D' onclick='checkthis();'>  $opt4</label>
<div class='row top'>
    <div class='col-md-6'>
    <button class='btn' id='btn' disabled>Submit</button>   
    </div>
</div>
</form>
```

Comment: Just put the script after the html.. or use jQuery's document ready.. You are welcome (in advance).. by the way in this code you are not calling your js function.

Comment: There is no iframe if you code example.

Comment: Does the iframe load jQuery?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

please make sure that inside the iframe you call jQuery.js - otherwise iframe won't be able to run jquery

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<script>
function checkthis(){      
$('#btn').prop('disabled', false);  
}
</script>


<form name='opt' action='check' role='form' method='post'>          
    <label class='block'><input type='radio' name='ans' value='A' onclick='checkthis();'>  $opt1</label>
    <label class='block'><input type='radio' name='ans' value='B' onclick='checkthis();'>  $opt2</label>
    <label class='block'><input type='radio' name='ans' value='C' onclick='checkthis();'>  $opt3</label>
    <label class='block'><input type='radio' name='ans' value='D' onclick='checkthis();'>  $opt4</label>
<div class='row top'>
    <div class='col-md-6'>
    <button class='btn' id='btn' disabled>Submit</button>   
    </div>
</div>
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks! I edited my post, I hope you can give me an example or simple modification on my code to make it work. I am really noob in programming. :(